# Can I customize SharePoint Modern Teams site global menu style?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-team-site

Anyone got any easyish ideas for styling this global nav menu in a modern UI SharePoint Team site?
The text is so tiny these days, and the child site model works better for this team as all content is managed by the Learning&Development group.
(Big Global org, so no access to use PnP SPFx, and no chance to change tenancy settings. Need something we can do at a Site collection level really).
Google is not my friend today! Is there anything we can do?
[image: Can this menu be formatted?]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that nav. Instead set your Team site as a Hub site so you get the modern nav.

Alternatively if you don't want to Hubify the Team site, you can use a Comm site which has the same modern nav without being a hub.

Manipulating the DOM via CSS/JS in modern sites is unsupported and customizations will likely break over time as Microsoft makes changes to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB settings to change the style/look for the Global Navigation in modern Team Sites. This option is available in [Communication Sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/plan-navigation-modern-experience#navigation-menus-in-sharepoint) though.

If you are not open for using SharePoint Framework (which is also not recommended, as Trevor says), then you are out of options.